# How we can write in a file through a j2me code?

Tags: java-me

How we can write in a file through a j2me code ?

Answer (score 2):

Does your J2ME support JSR-75? If so, [see here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-access-local-file-systems-from-j2me-devices-using-fileconnectio-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/

this is he JSR75 spec, basically it just means to create a connector (FileConnectoion) and open a stream, once you hve it you can do various operation with hte file like chance to hidden, delete, create open etc..

If JSR-75 does not exists on the device (rare these days) your ownly options for storage is RMS, and if you want just to read files you have in your application you can use class.OpenResourceasStream(resname);